# Transparent Widget Background in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a notification widget project in Swift.I am trying to customise my widget background to transparent like a screenshot below.

My Code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    view.isOpaque = false
}
```

And I also tried blurView but it didn't make much different...

[image]

Comment: looks like the upper one with blur

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil Yes widget looks blurry. But i am not using blurView.Do you have any answer how to do it...thanks

Comment: you can use [this](https://github.com/KyoheiG3/DynamicBlurView)

Comment: @ÖzgürErsil thanks i will give it a go....